# Pushforward of structure sheaf on quotient surface singularity

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory, algebraic-surfaces

Let $f:\mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}^2/G$ be a quotient surface singularity. What properties should $G$ have such that the pushforward $f_*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^2}$, of the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^2}$, contains a direct summand isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^2/G}$?

Comment: If $G$ is finite, that is always true: the splitting is defined by averaging (sometimes called a "Reynolds operator").